# Delete string after '#' using sed

Tags: sed

I have a text file that looks like:

```
#filelists.txt
a
# aaa
b
#bbb
c #ccc
```

I want to delete parts of lines starting with '#' and afterwards, if line starts with #, then to delete whole line.

So I use 'sed' command in my shell:

```sh
sed -e "s/#*//g" -e "/^$/d" filelists.txt
```

I wish its result is:

```
a
b
c
```

but actually result is:

```
filelists.txt
a
 aaa
b
bbb
c ccc
```

What's wrong in my "sed" command?

I know '*' which means "any", so I think that '#*' means string after "#".

Isn't it?

Comment: `#*` means zero or more of `#`.  To make this work you need `#.*` where `.` means any character and the star then gives zero or more of any character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
sed 's/#.*//;/^$/d' file > outfile
```

The `s/#.*//` removes `#` and all the rest of the line and `/^$/d` drops empty lines.

See an [online test](https://ideone.com/78IUpr):

```
s="#filelists.txt
a
# aaa
b
#bbb
c #ccc"

sed 's/#.*//;/^$/d' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
a
b
c
```

Another idea: match lines having `#`, then remove `#` and the rest of the line there and drop if the line is empty:

```
sed '/#/{s/#.*//;/^$/d}' file > outfile
```

See [another online demo](https://ideone.com/CeCqQx).

This way, you keep the original empty lines.

Comment: HI @Wiktor Stribiżew: Does ';' is equivalent to 'sed -e'?

Comment: @curlywei Well, I understand it as an action sequence operator, the operation on the right side is performed after the operation on the left side of it.

Answer (score 2):

`*` does not mean "any" (at least not in regular expression context). `*` means "zero or more of the preceding pattern element". Which means you are deleting "zero or more `#`". Since you only have one `#`, you delete it, and the rest of the line is intact.

You need `s/#.*//`: "delete `#` followed by zero or more of any character".

EDIT: was suggesting `grep -v`, but didn't notice the third example (`#` in the middle of the line).

Comment: Hi @Amadan: Does "." of "#."  mean "followed by zero or more of any character"

Comment: `.` is just "any character". `.*` is "zero or more of any character".

Comment: The ```#.``` means first after ```#```,  ```#..``` means 2 characters after ```#```, ```#.*``` means lots of characters after ```#```